# Disappearing geo info when using SimpleXMLObject

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to an xml response to object via SimpleXMLElement. But an element of XML disappears with this operation. Take a look at XML and SimpleXMLElement clearly:

```
<item><pubDate>Wed, 28 Dec 2011 13:04:30 GMT</pubDate><title>M 1.2, Nevada</title><description>December 28, 2011 13:04:30 GMT</description><link>http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/recenteqsus/Quakes/nn00361989.php</link><geo:lat>37.4048</geo:lat><geo:long>-117.0953</geo:long><dc:subject>1</dc:subject><dc:subject>pasthour</dc:subject><dc:subject>7.00 km</dc:subject><guid isPermaLink="false">nn00361989</guid></item>
```

And here is the SimpleXMLElement return:

```
[item] => SimpleXMLElement Object
       (
           [pubDate] => Wed, 28 Dec 2011 13:04:30 GMT
           [title] => M 1.2, Nevada
           [description] => December 28, 2011 13:04:30 GMT
           [link] => http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/recenteqsus/Quakes/nn00361989.php
           [guid] => nn00361989
       )
```

As you see there's not geo lat and long info here. I am trying this code for creating SimpleXMLObject:

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($response)
```

Must i use an parameter with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geodata is namespaced in the XML, so you need to tell simplexml that there is also data namespaced with 'geo'

```
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($response)
$namespaces = $doc->getNamespaces(true);
$docGeoData = $doc->item->children($namespaces['geo']);
```

Note that your xml fragment is badly formed because there's no namespace declarations

Comment: lol :) it's not mine but from a government website: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/eqs1hour-M1.xml

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try simplexml_load_file

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file($response)
```